# JavaScript - Loading Bluebird module using requireJS

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, bluebird

I am running a purely JavaScript project (not using node) and I need to load a module for Promises called Bluebird.
I'm not experienced in loading modules with JavaScript, I've always used mean stack in the past.

I have the following in index.html:

```
<script data-main="assets/js/app/App.js" src="assets/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app/App.js"></script>
```

I read online that in my App.js I should have:

```
define(["bluebird"],function(Promise){
   //load modules
});
```

The problem is that I don't know what to put in place of "//load modules" to load up the bluebird.js. I've tried using:

```
define(["bluebird"],function(Promise){
   Promise = require('bluebird');
});
```

But this has the error:

```
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (Promise){
   Promise = require('bluebird');
}
```

Note that I did try just using `var Promise = require('bluebird');` but this returned `Uncaught Error: Module name "bluebird" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Did you check the documentation/examples for requireJS...?

Comment: Hi, I did check http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch to see how to fix the errors, and using `require(['bluebird'], function (Promise) { // module loaded});` loads fine but then the rest of my App.js doesn't work so I must be doing something wrong in how I'm loading requirejs.

Comment: The usage example [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#usage) looks very different from what you have.

Comment: Right-o, the code `require(['bluebird'], function (Promise) { // module loaded});` was working as expected (and as per the documentation) but due to the change in layout, my App was failing to load correctly because of some code in index.html. Fixed this and it's working. I'll update the fix on the ticket. Thanks.

Comment: @Gary I've removed the solution you added to your question. If you want to post a solution, post it as an answer, please.

Comment: @Louis Sure thanks. I'll accept it as the answer in 2 days (seems I can't right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up my original code from the requirejs error doc was correct but I had problems in my index.html which were causing it to fail.

The correct way to include bluebird would be:

```
require(['bluebird'], function (Promise) { //module loaded });
```

In `//module loaded` you need to put the bulk of the App.js code.

You need to make sure you don't include a  for bluebird either if requirejs is loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    ...
}
```

Note that Bluebird module will NOT be delay loaded, this is simply a syntax sugar to make dependencies more readable.

Check
http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar